# limit in a metric space

Tags: limits, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ and $(X, d_1)$ be two metric spaces over the same set $X$.  Suppose that a sequence $(a_n)$ in $X$ converges in $(X, d)$ to $l$ and converges in $(X, d_1)$ to $l_1$.  Then must $l$ equal $l_1$?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @MikeEarnest I think it can be, because I can't find counterexamples. But I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the *set* isomorphism that swaps $0$ with $-1$, and fixes all other points. Define $d'$ by $$d'(x,y)=d(\varphi(x),\varphi(y)),$$and let $a_n=1/n$ for every $n$. Clearly, $a_n\to0$ in $d$, and $a_n\to-1$ in $d'$.